trying to plot a graph using matplotlib but showing this error

_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
C:/Users/91953/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/lib/tcl8.6          C:/Users/91953/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/lib/tcl8.6   C:/Users/91953/AppData/Local/Programs/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/91953/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/library C:/Users/91953/AppData/Local/Programs/library C:/Users/91953/AppData/Local/Programs/tcl8.6.14/library C:/Users/91953/AppData/Local/tcl8.6.14/library

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
Trying to plot a graph using this code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight") 
y_trial =[10,20,30]
plt.bar(x_trial, y_trial, color= "#444444",label  ="Trial")
plt.legend()
plt.title(" Total sales per region")
plt.xlabel("Region")
plt.ylabel("Sales")
plt.show()

Am I missing anything in the code or something else?
PS: I tried using 3.9 and 3.13 version also tried re installing pylance also tried reinstalling all libraries.

why do you import: pandas, numpy, Counter

Have you tried to copy the tkl and tcl folders to the directories showing above?

@rioV8 just part of code only shown here. and it is trial plot. other parts of coded that
